# Help needed regarding homogenous equations in algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, homogeneous-equation

I have just started with algebra and I see here something about homogenous equations but I am just not able to figure it out. I read this answer here,

[Homogenous equation in linear algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123029/homogenous-equation-in-linear-algebra)

But still, I couldn't figure it out, what it really means. Here is a photograph of what my book says. If possible please explain it to me! Also i read on google, there is something like non- homogenous equation too. Please explain to me that also.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How old is this book ? 1887 ? Can you please tell me the title and author?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Hi!  The book's name is "Higher Algebra" by Hall and Knight. And yeah, year was 1887.

Comment: And you got it from internet archive ? (a great site !)

Comment: Haha, no i actually have a copy of that. I downloaded it so that i can ask questions here on MSE ( by taking screenshots of the pages ) as i have no teacher to explain to me all the stuff that i read. 

Here's the link to the pdf

https://www.forgottenbooks.com/en/download/HigherAlgebra_10021865.pdf

Comment: Reading such an old book might be a bit hard for a beginner. Personally I like those books, but I first learnt from more modern sources. What is your ultimate goal ?

Comment: I am currently in high school but i want to have an advance understanding of common topics in mathematics like trigonometry, algebra, geometry and calculus. What would you recommend to me?

Comment: I must say  you have stumped me a little with that one, I dont have a ready recommendation. You could as that also ask that as a question here, explain who you are and what you need. I guess most important is to find one you like and are  comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A monomial in several variables has a degree, the sum of all the individual degrees. For example all of the following are degree $3$.
$$x^3,y^3,x^2y,xyz.$$

A polynomial is homogeneous if it is a sum of monomials all of the same degree.

The book is saying that if $P(x,y,z)$ is homogenous then say if degree $k$, then 
$$P(ax,ay,az)=a^kP(x,y,z)$$
So multiplying the variables by a constant $a$ does not change an equation $P(x,y,z)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will get back to here after I've read it thoroughly .