# What does $ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ and null set mean? (Homogeneous system)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

So what does $ x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n$ mean when discussing homogeneous matrices? I have never seen this notation before and yet it was used in one of my linear algebra lectures.

We were talking about homogenous matrices.

I was given the following definition and proposition.

Definition:
The set $\{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n | Ax = 0\}$ is the null set of $A$.

Proposition:
If $p$ is a vector such that $Ap = b$, then $\{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^n | Ax = b\}$ = $\{y + p| y ∈ NS(A)\}$

I am just so perplexed by the sudden introduction of notations and all of the null set. Can someone please explain this in simple terms and explain what the notations are??

Thanks <3.

Comment: It means that $x$ is an $n$-uple of *reals*.

Comment: The null set is what the definition says - it is the set of vectors in $n-$dimensional real space which are taken to zero (the zero vector) when they are multiplied by (transformed by) the matrix $A$. "Null" in mathematics often has to do with something becoming zero when transformed or multiplied or by whatever process is being considered. Then the proposition says that any two vectors which are taken by $A$ to the same vector always differ by an element of the null set and that vectors which differ by an element of the null always set give the same outcome.

Comment: The term "homogeneous matrix" is very misleading. You deal with homogeneous systems, that's all. See [this interesting answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123044) for a wider view.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that this is the first time that you have encountered [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate). The expression $\{x \in \Bbb R^n \mid Ax = 0\}$ can be expressed in English as "the set of $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax = 0$". Here, $\Bbb R^n$ refers to the set of all column-vectors that contain $n$ real numbers.

To put this another way, the null set of $A$ is the set of solutions to the equation
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn}}
\pmatrix{x_1\\ \vdots \\ x_n} = \pmatrix{0\\ \vdots \\ 0},
$$
where we think of the column of values $x_1,\dots,x_n$ as the single vector "$x$".

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your simple answer! I thought it was saying "real number power by $n$".